# cast numbers and decimals into INT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have [funds] that have been presented in different formats, some are decimals, others numbers:

```
Null
0.00
0.55
55
55555555555
```

etc

I tried to use this:
,CAST (REPLACE ([funds],'.','') AS INT) AS [funds]

but got this mistake:

The conversion of the varchar value '288294130100' overflowed an int column.

How do I ned to treat the combo of numbers and decimals?

Comment: 288294130100 is larger than a **Integer** can store, instead use **Long**, actually I think you'll need an even a larger type like **BIGINT**. See this link for the DataTypes sizes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=msvc-170

Comment: The varchar col is implicitly converted to an int and is overflowing (i.e. is >larger than 2,147,483,647). To resolve this try casting the columns to bigint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast them to BIGINT. But, when you cast to BIGINT, the decimal places will be lost.

```sql
SELECT cast(v as bigint) as bigvalue FROM (
VALUES
(Null)
,(0.00)
,(0.55)
,(55  )
,(55555555555)
,(288294130100)) as t(v)
```

| bigvalue |
| --- |
| NULL |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 55 |
| 55555555555 |
| 288294130100 |